# SSIS: How to split excel cell value into SQL columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, ssis, split

I have an excel file with data like this:

```
ID | FieldA | FieldB 
1    ABC      A, B   
2    FGH      W, Z   
3    KLÑ      G, K
```

What I want to do is to use SSIS and import this data into a SQL Table. The only problem is that this table has an structure like this:

```
ID | FieldA | FieldB1 | FieldB2
```

So, what I need to do is to split the "FieldB" Column in Excel and put it into FieldB1 and FieldB2 in SQL.

The result would be something like this:

```
ID | FieldA | FieldB1 | FieldB2 
1  | ABC    | A       | B
2  | FGH    | W       | Z
3  | KLÑ    | G       | K
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, I'd just skip the header row and have it import the subsequent data correctly. Take a minute or so to assign column names and voilà, done.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the relevant range, then running this:

```
Sub SplitColumn()

  Dim strArr() as String
  Dim cell as Range

  For Each cell In Selection
    cell.offset(0, 1).resize(1,2).value = split(cell.value,", ")
  Next cell

End Sub
```

Now copy and paste your data wherever required.

Non-VBA alternative:
Enter the following formula in cell D2:

```
=LEFT(C2,FIND(",",C2)-1)
```

And in E2:

```
=RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND(", ",C2)-1)
```

And autocomplete the rest of the column.

Answer (score 0):

As I see [here](http://bi-polar23.blogspot.com/2008/06/splitting-delimited-column-in-ssis.html) is a detailed explanation of your example.

On the other side you can use another approach - split one excel column on two columns in excel using excel formulas and import document with 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can use derived column and add as two new columns .First Column expression should be like this :

```
SUBSTRING([FieldB],1,FINDSTRING([FieldB],",",1) - 1)
```

and the second one like this :

```
SUBSTRING([FieldB],FINDSTRING([FieldB],",",1) + 1,LEN([FieldB])- FINDSTRING([FieldB],"_",1) )
```